# Proper Format of Vertex AI AutoML Action Recognition Data Labels

Tags: google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, automl, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm trying to build an action recognition model in Vertex AI AutoML. I've studied the documentation thoroughly, but so far my model is not able to make any decent predictions in the wild. I've made three attempts so far, and my most recent attempt had a precision-recall curve that could be described as 'respectable', but the predictions are really awful. I'll try to explain my process below as best as I can.

### The Raw Data

I recorded the same action in 34 ~3 min videos, with the number of actions in each video varying between 30 and 100. The actions themselves take < 1 second. I recorded the data from 4 cameras at multiple angles, and because I was moving around a lot, there was plenty of variance in each action performed. While each raw video contains only one action, there are a total of six classes of action we hope to identify.

### First Model Attempt

According to the Vertex AI documentation, it's expecting time segments for the actions The annotation JSONL/CSV documentation says as much, but somewhere else in the documentation it says it's expecting the maximal point at which the action is performed if you wish to label the videos inside the console. Anyways, I created a labeling job and my team and I labeled all the time segments for the actions in the videos. The precision-recall curve alluded to some kind of data leakage, and when we inspected the batch prediction results we discovered that it appeared that the model was training on the 0th frame of the time segment. We were careful not to include any frames that weren't part of the action, but due to the nature of the actions, they all essentially start and end at a 'neutral' spot. At seemingly random intervals in the video, multiple or all actions would be labeled, but ONLY in those spots.

### Second Attempt

We took the annotation data that we had built with the labeling job and chopped up the original videos into a series of subclips. We had all the labels and the time segments, so we did this with a simple script. We did not remove any of the frames of the video, so the neutral position in the beginning and end frames were still present. The precision-recall curve again looked suspicious, but slightly better. Inference in the wild yielded the same results.

### Third Attempt

After further reviewing the documentation, Vertex AI appeared to contradict itself in what it expects in the data labels:

> When the action starts appearing that you want to identify, slowly
> progress through till you find the center or the most representative
> moment of the action using "Next frame" option.

To avoid spending a ton of time on another labeling task (takes us about three days), we labeled a subset of the original subclip dataset according to this information and trained a model to analyze the precision-recall curve. FINALLY something much more respectable. However, the inferences in the wild were still terrible, suffering from the same.

My question is: **do I need to annotate negative action sequences?** In the object tracking or object detection documentation it says that adding a `None_of_the_above` label would help the model to identify that which it doesn't need to focus on. And again in the action recognition documentation it points out a limitation in the labeling console:

> Limitation: There's a limitation when using the VAR labeling console,
> which means if you want to use the labeling tool to label actions, you
> must label all the actions in that video.

I can write a script to fill in the dead space in the video as a negative action sequence, but I'd like to know what the best practice is before going down that route and spending the money to train yet another terrible model.

Comment: I couldn’t find any information regarding the implementation that you are trying to do, but I found that as you mentioned in your question, you can try and add the None_of_the_above label if this doesn’t help you, you might need to train another model.

Comment: Thanks, @EduardoOrtiz! While I was waiting I started with NVIDIA's ActionRecognitionNet notebook, which seems promising. While it is training, I will add the negative action annotations to my maximal action point subclips dataset and try again.

Comment: It's been 11 months when you asked... Have achieved what you want??